# Wpf Absolute vs. Relative Pack URIs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

**My question is: Am I reading MSDN wrong OR is MSDN wrong?** I am trying to reference an image *Resource* via relative URI.

The MSDN page titled **Pack URIs in WPF** clearly states that:

*"Resource file in subfolder of local assembly" =* "**/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml**"

in Table 2: Relative URIs in Markup (here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa970069.aspx ).

So, I created new WPF/.NET 4.0 projects in Vs2010 (v10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) to test.

```
Startup Project: TryUri
    App.xaml
    MainWindow.xaml
Custom Ctrl Project: TryUri.CCL
    Icons/folder.png <-- Marked As Resource!
    Views/TestUC.xaml
```

In TestUC.xaml:

```
<Canvas>
    <Border>
        <Image Source="/Icons/folder.png" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
// xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:TryUri.CCL.Views;assembly=TryUri.CCL"

<uc:TestUC />
```

Result: *The image does not show up!!*

When I change the path to "../Icons/folder.png" **It does work.**

If I copy the Icons/folder.png into the TryUri.CCL/Views/ folder, then "Icons/folder.png" works.

However, I can never get a leading forward slash to work as in "/Icons/folder.png" the way that MSDN states.

Comment: My guess is that your working directory is set wrong in your project.  I would check that first.

Comment: The working directory would matter if I were trying to access the png as a file. I'm not, it's marked as a Resource. I updated the question to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: I self-answered below. For my project I have chosen to simply use paths relative to the markup (i.e. "../icons/folder.png") as that is the simplest choice IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason, when running as a separate assembly, that your Relative Pack URI must begin with `../` or no leading backslash is because of how relative URIs are used, [from MSDN (emphasis mine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx):

> **Absolute vs. Relative Pack URIs**
>
> ...
>
> If a **leading backslash** is used, however, the relative pack URI reference is then considered **relative to the root of the application**.

Therefore if you'd like the images to remain relative to your referenced assembly, simply omit the leading slash or use `../` if in a sub-folder.

See the image below for an example of how this looks at runtime:

[image: Absolute vs. Relative Pack URIs]

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work with a leading slash. I have to use "Icons/folder.png" for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you comment with a link to your code? I am curious how you got that to work. Also, it looks like you left your TestUC and TestUC2.xaml in the /Views folder of WpfControlLibrary1 contrary to your answer.

Comment: I'm revising my answer, I believe the `..` is required because of how your `UserControl` is used at run time.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is this: *The leading slash in a relative path always resolves to the main assembly, NOT the assembly that the markup is in.*

To make it work the way that MSDN states, I would have to store all icons in an "Icons/" folder in the main assembly, instead of in the custom control dll.

If you choose to store the resources in the dll assembly in an "Icons/" folder, you must reference them with a path relative to the markup you're working on (i.e. "`../Icons/folder.png`") OR you must qualify the path with the assembly name (i.e. "`/AssemblyName;component/Icons/folder.png`")

Answer (score 4):

Just replace < ApplicationName> with the name of your application and this should work

```
Source="/<ApplicationName>;component/Icons/folder.png"
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that will work, but I want to know why MSDN says that I can just do "/Subfolder/Resource.file-ext".