# Issues with displaying images on buttons with xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to xaml. I made 2 buttons with the same event handler. So when I click a button, it will add an image to it. The problem is that when I click another button, the image on the previous button disappear. 
How can I keep the image on the previous button when I click another one?

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="image1" Source="folder\image1.png" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
       <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Clickable"/>
       <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="315,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Clickable"/>
   </Grid>
```

//event handler

```
private void Clickable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        Button a = (Button)sender;
        a.Content = FindResource("image1");
   }
```

Comment: is it necessary to do this in the same events?

Comment: Yea because I will have like 20-30 buttons.

Comment: maybe if you try any other methods instead of FindResource() you achieve.

Comment: What would be the other methods?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add  `x:Shared="False"` to your Image resource. This will create multiple instances of your resource. Read more

1. [Shujaat.net](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/xshared-for-sharing-resources.html)
2. [Daily Dotnet Tips](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/07/25/use-xshared-to-write-your-frameworkelements-directly-as-resource/)

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly. I also have another question if you don't mind.   
<Image x:Key="image1" Source="folder\image1.png" />
My source is actually in absolute path. Is there a way to make it relative path?

Comment: If the answer helps you, first mark it as answer. This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772163/wpf-absolute-vs-relative-pack-uris

Answer (score 0):

Try this. BTW, I think writting a new controlTemplete is better.

```
private void Clickable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button a = (Button)sender;

    a.Content = new Image() {Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"folder/image1.png",UriKind.Relative)) };
}
```

Comment: It works! I don't really know this method, could you explain to me why it's better than image resource? Also, do you happen to know how to make a relative path? I had to use absolute path in "...new uri(@".../image1.png" in order to make it work.

Comment: Hey, @".../image1.png"  already is a Relative path. Absolute path maybe like this@"C:/xxx/xxx/image1.png". I think this method is same with image resource, and they all create a new image instance. BTW, could you vote my answer? I am a new comer here and need some reputation

Comment: Better use image resources. Set the `Build Action` of the image files to `Resource` (in the Properties window in VS), don't copy them to the output directory, and load them by a [WPF Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) like `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/folder/image1.png")`. This is the preferred way to load images in a WPF application (in code behind).

Answer (score -1):

you can try this for resulting in one event:

```
private void Clickable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender.Name == "button")
    {
       button.Content = FindResource("image1");
    }
    else
    {
       button_Copy.Content = FindResource("image1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have like 20 buttons? Do I have to manually type all this?